# Windows Service running as LocalSystem but needs to start a process as the currently logged on user

Tags: .net, windows-services, process, impersonation

I'm running a windows service (written using .NET) as the user - LocalSystem.

From the service, I need to start a process but as the currently logged on user. If I user Process.Start(process_name), it runs with the privilege of the service by default - that's as LocalSystem. How do I impersonate the currently logged on user and run the process under the same?

**EDIT**: I won't have access to user credentials - I wouldn't know the password of the logged in user

**EDIT2**: The 2nd comment in the post marked as answer is what helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question similar to this has already been asked [Setting Service to Run as Current User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487638/wix-serviceinstall-setting-the-service-to-run-as-the-current-windows-user)

Comment: Yeah, that's a little different. I install and run my service as - LocalSystem. I need this service, which is running with elevated privileges to start a process with lower privilege - that's as the current user.

Comment: Ah I see, ok what about getting the service to create a scheduled task that will run your program? Or put an entry into the startup menu to run when then login?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a process using [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) - it allows you to set a username and password for the new process to start as:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.UserName = myUserName;
startInfo.Password = myUserPassword;
startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

**Update:** (following update to question)

You *may* be able to use [`RunAs`](http://RunAs) for this - if someone else provides the credentials.

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to mention - i cannot rely on passing user credentials - no password :)